# Интерфейс окна в стиле Ribbon

Tags: visual-basic, visual-studio

Все наверняка знают, что такое Paint. У них при запуске программы выскакивает форма. Вопрос в том - как сделать такое оформление? Возможно ли средствами VB 2010 Express такое учудить? Для тех, кто знает.

[image: панель].

Answer (score 2):

Возможно. Используйте [Microsoft Ribbon for WPF](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=11877). Это управляемая версия контрола для WPF. В загружаемом архиве есть примеры использования на C#, по аналогии можно сделать для Visual Basic.

Answer (score 0):

Под Windows Forms можно воспользоваться библиотекой [Elegant Ribbon](http://www.prof-uis.com/elegant-ribbon/net-winforms-controls.aspx).